# Computing Chi-square values from Schoenfeld residuals

Tags: survival, chi-squared-test, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

Based on page 164-165 of [Collett:Modelling Survival data in medical research (Third edition-2014)] the Schoenfeld for individual test and for global test can be obtained as follows[1][image: Schoenfeld formula].

However, computing the Chi-square values using own code gives different answers as using cox.zph(res.cox). Survival package version used is survival_3.1-12

```
rm(list=ls()); set.seed(1234)
 library("survival")
 hmohiv<-read.table("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/asa/hmohiv.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE)
 #______Schoenfeld Residuals from coxph()__________
 res.cox<-coxph( Surv(time, censor)~drug+age, data=hmohiv,ties="breslow")
 sresid <- residuals(res.cox, "schoenfeld")
 #______________Own code__________
 beta<-as.matrix( c (res.cox$coefficients[1], res.cox$coefficients[2]) )
 OrderedData <- hmohiv[order(hmohiv$time), ] #order the data according to the event times
 x_ordered<-as.matrix(OrderedData[ ,4:3]) #Consider x1 and x2.
 n<-nrow(OrderedData)
 Numerator1<-numeric(n);Numerator2<-  numeric(n);Denominator<-numeric(n)
 Num1<-  numeric(n);Num2<-  numeric(n);Den<-numeric(n)
 for(j in 1:n) { 
  Numerator1[j] <- x_ordered[j,1]*exp( x_ordered[j,]%*%beta) 
  Numerator2[j] <- x_ordered[j,2]*exp( x_ordered[j,]%*%beta)     
  Denominator[j]<-exp( x_ordered[j,] %*%beta) 
 }
 
 for(j in 1:n) {
   thistime<-OrderedData$time[j]
   riskset <- which(thistime<=OrderedData$time)
   Num1[j] <- sum(Numerator1[riskset])
   Num2[j]<- sum(Numerator2[riskset])
   Den[j] <- sum(Denominator[riskset]) 
 }
 
Schoenfeld<-as.matrix(cbind( (x_ordered[,1]-Num1/Den), (x_ordered[,2]-Num2/Den))  )
Schoenfeldr<- Schoenfeld[OrderedData$censor==1, ]


> OrderedData.Cens<- OrderedData[OrderedData$censor==1, ]
> ObservedTime<- OrderedData.Cens$time
> sch1 <- residuals(res.cox,"scaledsch")

> xx <- ObservedTime - mean(ObservedTime)
> #__________Schoefeld Individual test__________#
> temp1 <- xx %*% sch1 #sch1 : Scaled Schoenfeld residual
> temp2 <-  res.cox$var  # Variance covariance matrix
> test1.Value <- temp1[1] %*% t(temp1)[1] /
  ( length(ObservedTime) *temp2[1,1]* sum(xx^2) )
> test2.Value <- temp1[2] %*% t(temp1)[2] /
   ( length(ObservedTime) *temp2[2,2]* sum(xx^2) )
> #_________Global test_________________#
> temp1 <- xx %*%  Schoenfeldr # Unscaled Schoenfeld Residuals
> test.Global<- temp1 %*% temp2  %*% t(temp1) /
   ( sum(xx^2) / length(ObservedTime) )

> data.frame(test1.Value ,test2.Value,test.Global )
  test1.Value test2.Value test.Global
  0.2113885  0.01205375   0.2502792

> test.ph <- cox.zph(res.cox)
> test.ph
          chisq df    p
drug   4.98e-06  1 1.00
age    8.05e-02  1 0.78
GLOBAL 8.64e-02  2 0.96
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the publication date of the reference and the `survival` software package version that you used. The details of `cox.zph()` calculations changed in the past few years. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478957/28500) for some details.

Comment: Thanks for updating the information on the reference. Please report the version of `survival` that _you_ used, e.g. reported by the `sessionInfo()` function. You seem to be using a more recent version than the book, as your `cox.zph()` doesn't report a "rho" value like the older versions did.

Comment: Survival package version used is survival_3.1-12. This has been updated in the question.

Comment: @EdM Do you have a reference for formulation procedure of the actual score test?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the most recent `cox.zph` code. An answer below has a link to an early version of the prior code.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work, for three reasons

1. That's not the test that `cox.zph` does. It hasn't been for years (as the comments point out).  It now does the actual score test.
2. You're looking at the correlation between the Schoenfeld residuals and `time`; the default in `cox.zph` is to use the Kaplan-Meier estimator instead of just time.
3. You can't get around the issue of ties in this setting just by using `ties="breslow"` because `cox.zph` always uses `ties="efron"`.

If you fix the second issue by comparing to `cox.zph(res.cox, transform="identity")` it will be a lot closer.

Alternatively, the old code that does the test you are doing is [here](https://github.com/cran/survival5/blob/master/R/cox.zph.s)

Comment: Do you have a reference for formulation procedure of the actual score test?

Comment: No, not other than the code. The developer, Terry Therneau, might well be able to give you something.